# Transformation $(\mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{v}_0) \mapsto (\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{v})$ has unit Jacobian

Tags: classical-mechanics

I was reading paper by Low 1958 and there he remarked that the following transformation has unit Jacobian.

Define $\mathbf{x}_0$, $\mathbf{v}_0$ be variables that at the initial time $t_0$ represent position and velocity of particle. Then, assume that $\mathbf{x}=\phi_t (\mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{v}_0)$ be a solution for a position of a particle starting at respective initial position, velocity, at time $(t_0+t)$. Similarly, define $\mathbf{v} = \phi_t (\mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{v}_0)$ be a solution for a velocity of a particle.

Claim : Jacobian constructed from taking determinant of a map $\phi_t$ at fixed $t$ is one.

I am not sure where this comes from or how to prove it. In a paper it was said that it is a well known result, but unfortunately no references were given.

Reference: F.E.Low "A Lagrangian formulation of the Boltzmann-Vlasov equation for plasmas", 1958

Comment: Isn't this just time evolution? This is a well-known canonical transformation, and these always have trivial Jacobian.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform can you please supply a proof or reference? Also, does this assume we are doing Hamiltonian mechanics / no coupling to EM (so that p=mv?